# Delete folders older than x days with wildcard in foldername

Tags: windows, batch, script

I need to delete all folders and their contents starting with the name `daily` after 30 days, and all folders starting with the name `monthly` after 365 days.  Unfortunately, the daily and monthly backups have to be in the same folder.
Here is the script I'm trying to use, but it's not liking the wildcard. Any suggestions?

```
forfiles -p u:\backups\daily* -d 30 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
forfiles -p u:\backups\monthly* -d 365 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE /rd /S /Q @path"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the match parameter:

```
 forfiles -p u:\backups -m daily* -d 30 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
 forfiles -p u:\backups -m monthly* -d 365 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE /rd /S /Q @path"
```